# How to handle two possible object in a http response in Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, http, observable

I'm in angular 5 sending a http:post method, and expecting to get some data, but if there is an error, the server will send me a different data structure. I mean, a different object. 
I had created two class, one for the correct response and another one for the error response.

Maybe it is with an Observable. I'm confused.

After make a login, I got this:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 299,
    "access_token": "da7a2180c2883ff8dasdsadsc84",
    "refresh_token": "def502000396e1de7a2180c2883ff8c84"
}
```

But if my request fails, I got this:

```
{ 
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "message": "a long message that nobody reads... ",
    "hint": "Check the configuration to see if the grant is enabled."
}
```

The class that will get the response is this one:

```
export class token {
        token_type: string;
        expires_in: number;
        access_token: string;
        refresh_token: string;
    }
```

And the class for get the fail response is this one:

```
export class error
    {
        error: string;
        message: string;
        hint: string;
    }
```

And this is the http.post :

```
  login (token: Token): Observable<Token> {
      const url = `${this.mainUrl}user/login?_format=json`;  
      const loginReturn = this.http.post(url, token);     
      console.log (loginReturn);    

      return loginReturn 
      .map((token: Token) => 
        {
            if (token && token.access_token){
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                 localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.access_token));
            }
        // console.log ('localstorage ' + localStorage['token']);
        return token;
       })   
  }
```

Comment: do you receive in both cases a HttpStatusCode 200 ? that would be weird since 200 is sucess, and 4xx or 5xx are used for erro handling

Comment: Good point @BenCroughs I receive in the good scenario a 200 Ok and in the wrong a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Then your code is fine (except for its disrespect of naming conventions). What's the problem?

Comment: I want to use the data from the response @JBNizet

Comment: You are already. If you want to do something with the error, then use catch, or subscribe and pass an error callback. In both cases, you'll get an error as argument (if the server indeed sends that error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach a `.catch()` to your request

```
login (token: Token): Observable<Token> {
    ...
    return loginReturn 
        .map((token: Token) => ..)
        .catch((error) => throw Observable.throw(err))
}
```

Then you can use the error callback in you `.subscribe()`

```
loginService.login(token)
    .subscribe(
        (data) => ...,
        (error) => ...handle error...
    )
```

Comment: But that means dont use the error class? just the `400 bad request`response. ?

Comment: Your backend should return a http error code + a error message. Your error message can be in a structure of your error object.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [**union type**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) - `Token | Error` that will mean your return type is either  `Observable<Token>` or `Observable<Error>`

```
login (token: Token): Observable<Token | Error> {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your const loginReturn is of type response https://angular.io/api/http/Response , on that object you have

- either a boolean **ok** that is true for good calls and false for error calls like the 400
- or a a field **status** that contains the HttpStatusCode of the server

so you should do your mapping code when the **ok === true**, when the bool is false, you could do some generic error handling

or

even wrap a parent object around your token/error, containing the same bool, so you can handle the error in the component calling this service and return that and do some handling there

```
export class response {
  token: token,
  error: error,
  ok: boolean
}
```